# Как работает атрибут nonce?

Tags: html, атрибуты

Как работает атрибут nonce (для html-элемента link)? И непонятно для чего он вообще нужен?

Answer (score 7):

Атрибут `nonce` с помощью CSP определяет, для каких `html` файлов может быть загружен тот или иной файл стилей или скриптов. По существу, аналог токена для формы.

Подробно механизм работы описан на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922784/what-s-the-purpose-of-the-html-nonce-attribute-for-script-and-style-elements). Но есть и описание на русском:

Nonce — это генерируемая случайным образом на сервере строковая переменная. Она добавляется в CSP-заголовок:

```
Content-Security-Policy:    default-src 'self';
                            script-src 'self' 'nonce-Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu';
```

и в тэг инлайн-скрипта:

```
<script>
    console.log("Script won't run as it doesn't contain a nonce attribute");
</script>

<script nonce="Eskdikejidojdk978Ad8jf">
    console.log("Script won't run as it has an invalid nonce");
</script>

<script nonce="Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu">
    console.log('Script runs as the nonce matches the nonce in the HTTP header');
```

Если вы захотите использовать хэши, то сначала их нужно сгенерировать на сервере и включить в заголовок CSP, соответственно в директивы `style-src` или `script-src`. Перед рендерингом страницы браузер вычисляет хэш скрипта/стиля, и если он совпадает с указанным, то выполнение разрешается.

Пример хэша, сгенерированного из строковой `console.log('Hello, SitePoint');` с помощью алгоритма Sha256 (base64).

```
Content-Security-Policy: 
                default-src 'self';
                script-src 'self' 'sha256-V8ghUBat8RY1nqMBeNQlXGceJ4GMuwYA55n3cYBxxvs=';
```

Во время рендеринга страницы браузер для каждого инлайн-скрипта вычисляет хэши и сравнивает с перечисленными в CSP. Приведённый выше хэш позволяет выполнить скрипт:

```
< sсript >console.log('Hello, SitePoint');< /sсript >
```

Обратите внимание, что пробелы имеют значение, так что эти скрипты выполнены не будут:

```
<sсript> console.log('Hello, SitePoint');</sсript>
<sсript>console.log('Hello, SitePoint'); </sсript>
```

Оригинал можно прочитать здесь: [Улучшение сетевой безопасности с помощью Content Security Policy (Хабрахабр)](https://habrahabr.ru/company/nixsolutions/blog/271575/)

Примеры приведены для тега `script`, но для `link` смысл тот же.

Comment: Маловато будет. Переводите :Р

Comment: @Visman, любая профессия, связанная с IT, обязывает её обладателя владеть английским в объёме позволяющем, минимум, читать документацию. В крайнем случае, всегда можно воспользоваться онлайн переводчиком.

Comment: @Streletz тогда тот факт, что мы сейчас пишем на русскоязычном SO, является немного нелогичным сам по себе

Comment: @Streletz Простите, совершенно не понятно. Можете пояснить, каким образом он определяет, для каких файлов может быть загружено стилей или скрипт? - в значение nonce  нужно прописать список этих файлов или что? И что это даст? - будут подцеплены стили, которые в nonce? В чём идея? По ссылке ничего не понятно, там все по-английски.  Можете  перевести? - т.к. я не специалист  в IT, поэтому и обратился сюда с надеждой, что ответят специалисты. Кстати, если вы не в  курсе, онлайн-переводчик сильно искажает смысл, попробовал перевести с его помощью, стало ещё более непонятно

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, специально для Вас нашёл статью на русском языке, где всё это детально расписано.